# MATLAB - command window colours

Tags: matlab, customization

Is there a way to change the command window foreground and background colours in Matlab command window, invoked with the -nodesktop option? I'm using R2010a. I tried the java commands but they don't work for me.

Comment: Can you just change the Colors settings in the Preferences dialog? Or do these not hold when running under `-nodesktop`?

Comment: @SamRoberts No, there isn't even a way to do only the desktop in the preferences. Everything changes along with editor. There is a hack to do it with java. But then I don't it would hold in the nodesktop.

Comment: How are you starting MATLAB and what operating system are you using?  I use MATLAB on Linux with the nodesktop command, but I start the terminal from the bash terminal window (or Konsole depending on the environment).  In both situations, I use the native terminal settings to change the colors.

Comment: Matlab on linux starts in the linux terminal itself. But with windows, there is a separate window.